# Flutter with a Kotlin module: Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I tried using the flutter foreground task module in my project, but when running assembleDebug, I ran into the following error message (countless times):

```
 /.../ForegroundServiceUtils.kt: (82, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.The class is loaded from /.../jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
```

I read multiple solutions about flushing gradle caches, or upgrading the kotlin plugins (also some settings on the projects, that I don't even have on my AS), but nothing worked, so I'm pretty much lost. I tried a few JDK versions as well (1.8, 11, 17), but none worked out. For versions please see my flutter doctor output here:

```
   [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 5.13.0-30-generic, locale hu_HU.UTF-8)
        • Flutter version 2.10.3 at /home/ati/snap/flutter/common/flutter
        • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
        • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (2 days ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
        • Engine revision bd539267b4
        • Dart version 2.16.1
        • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /home/ati/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/119/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
    • cmake version 3.10.2
    • ninja version 1.8.2
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/119/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 64.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 211.7798
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code
    • VS Code at /snap/code/current
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • PRA LX1 (mobile) • 9DCDU17217012998 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
    • Linux (desktop)  • linux            • linux-x64     • Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 5.13.0-30-generic

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Do you have any suggestions? Was there anything that worked for you?flutter

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that although the version of plugins and everything was okay, but the actual kotlin config was missing from the gradle files. How was this possible? I'm unsure as everything was done via Android studio.
But anyway, if you run into the same message, make sure you have the following.

app/build.gradle should contain:

```
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
```

build.gradle should contain:

```
     dependencies {
        .....(whatever you have already) 
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
     }
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml, add the following property to your activity definition

```
android:exported="true"
```